# Windows Platform (UWP) App - mainpage .xaml page not displayed

Tags: windows, visual-studio, uwp, platform, universal

Im develop the Universal Windows Platform (UWP) App  , im add the new project , now displayed the following error 
how can i fix it, any help
what i update Windows 10 or Visual Studio 2015

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the error message clearly states, you have to update Windows 10...